# Shine on you crazy diamond (Pink floyd) tone

Tags: amplifiers, effects-pedal, tone

how to do I get the Shine on You Crazy Diamond(Pink Floyd) tone from my Amp(Harley benton hb20r). I also have three pedals (compressor, phaser and chorus).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

David Gilmour's tone is described on various sites, but the basic core of it is a clean tube amp with vintage pickups. His amps (Hiwatts) also have a lower mid range, so you can emulate that by turning down your mids, but even on the Hiwatts Gilmour has his mids at 40%, bass at 50% and treble up towards 60%.

If you have a delay pedal, that would help get you a more accurate sound.

Gilmourish.com reckons his pedal settings are:

- Boss Compressor (CS-2) set to level 2, attack 12 and sustain 11
- Boss Chorus (CE-2) set to rate 1 and depth 11
- Digital Delay of 440ms

Comment: Wasn’t aware of gilmourish.com before this post so thank you for that!